# Training loss reach to zero, then suddenly increases, then decreases to zero

Tags: optimization, loss-functions, training-error

I get the following loss behavior when training multilayer perceptron with mean squared error loss on some synthetic data using default Adam with default learning. (I am working on 1 demention data)

I am using the training data == validation data because I want my model to internationally the overfitting:

I am not using batchnormalization and dropout
[image]

Comment: what happens when you decrease your step size by 10 times? e.g. 0.01 instead of 0.1?

Comment: Was your training data constant during the 800 steps?

Comment: If it's not due to changes of the data during the converging, then I imagine that these extreme peaks might occur due to some parameters, when they are updated, having a large influence on the performance of other parameters. Then, if these updates happen randomly, as in stochastic gradient descent, then you can get these peaks. (The effect is a bit extreme though, but maybe you have parameters with extremely different scales and relative learning rates?)

Answer (score 2):

Such type of error plots may suggest the following occurred:

1. the order of the training objects was changed during sweeps, causing the learned
   connection weights to lose their predictive accuracy of the target
   values.  Neural network learning commonly becomes biased toward the order of training objects.
2. new (never seen before) training objects were introduced (like another fold for CV - see plot below)
3. the connection weights were wiped out or modified.

Batch vs. online learning won't affect MSE throughout training/validation/testing nearly as much as the above-listed issues will.

Below is a similar example showing what happens when new objects are introduced in each CV fold:

[image]